# Add Object to Array while looping

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

One of my PDO statements returns an array. For JSON encoding I want to cast this array to an Object and append it to another array.

```
     while($row = $sth->fetch()){
            foreach($row as $key=>$value){ 
                    $r = (object) $row;
                    $recordArray[] = $r;
            }
    }

    $json->record = $recordArray;
    echo json_encode($json);
```

`$recordArray` seems to stay empty but it doesn't if I write `$recordArray[] = "test"` in the loop. So there must be something wrong with my Object `$r` but I can't spot the mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easier way

```
echo json_encode(array('record'=>$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. If I do a `var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));`I get an array containing 194 objects (stdClass). But if I do the json_encode with the content of the var_dump I get a blank page.

Comment: I just tested this and it woks fine, are you outputting anything else to the page? try right click, view source, you should see the json string

Comment: Still can't spot the error. Guess there must be something wrong with my server. Thanks a lot for the shorter statement anyways.

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your php script and see if you're getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` is wrong: in body you use object on which you iterate.
May be you mean this?

```
$records = [];
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    $current = [];
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $current[$key] = $value;
    }
    $records[] = $current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to loop over `$row` and add every object within `$row` to `$recordArray`.

Then you should do this:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    foreach($row as $value){ 
        $recordArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```